# How to set visibility of Facebook profile likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How can I setup the visibility of profile photo likes? For example when anyone does not have me in friends, he can´t give me like and I want to anybody can give me like even if he hasn't me in friends.

Answer (score 0):

Change the audience setting to **Public**.

To make your current profile picture Public, click on the profile pic thumbnail or open that pic in your profile [picture album](https://www.facebook.com/help/215496745135618?helpref=about_content), then change the audience setting to **Public**. If you are adding a new profile picture, before posting [check the audience as Public](https://www.facebook.com/help/120939471321735?helpref=faq_content).

By setting audience as Public, anyone on Facebook can like your picture.

Learn more about [privacy settings](https://www.facebook.com/help/325807937506242/).

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to set the privacy of your photo to `Public`. This will allow people who are not your friends to *view* likes and comments.

The second step is to head into your [Public posts Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=followers&section=comment&view) and set **Public Post Comments** to `Public`as well.

[image: Public Post Comments]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the downward pointing arrow to the right of "Other Pages You Like." Select "Public" if you want everyone to see your likes or a more limited privacy option that corresponds to who you want to be able to see your likes. The option you select will take effect immediately
.

[how to hide photos on facebook](http://ustechportal.com/how-to-make-photos-private-on-facebook-how-to-hide-photos-on-facebook/)